# Snipmate plugin in vim inserts a carriage return in all snippets

Tags: vim, plugins, snippets

I'm using [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugin in vim, and started creating some snippets to use in Zope.

Unfortunately, the snippets I'm creating are some html attributes, and everytime I call the snippet, it works as expected **but** it inserts a carriage return after the snippet, and I have to return the end tag `>` to it's place everytime I run a snippet, thus losing productivity advantage in using snipmate.

How do I create a snippet that doesn't insert a carriage return after the snippet?

Comment: can't answer to your question, but i changed the template-system over to xtp-template (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. When you create your own snippets in your file:

```
snippet snippet1
    snippet1

snippet snippet2
    snippet2
```

This "space" between snippets is reponsible for the extra carriage return. If I maintain my snippets file like this:

```
snippet snippet1
    snippet1
snippet snippet2
    snippet2
```

It works as expected. The carriage return was being used as a snippet as well.

Comment: I swear I can't see the difference between the two.

Comment: There's a carriage return between the two snippets in the first example, the second there isn't. Snipmate thinks the carriage return between two snippets definitions is from the first snippet and call it when you execute the snippet in vim. If you don't want a carriage return after your snippet, you shouldn't separate snippet definitions with carriage returns.